# how to count duplicate values object to be a value of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

how to count the value of object in `new object` values
lets say that i have json like this :

```
let data = [{
    no: 3,
    name: 'drink'
  },
  {
    no: 90,
    name: 'eat'
  },
  {
    no: 20,
    name: 'swim'
  }
];
```

if i have the user pick no in arrays : `[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,90,20,20,20,20]`

so the output should be an array

```
[
 { 
   num: 3,
   total: 11
 },
 {
   num: 90,
   total: 1
 },
 {
   num:20,
   total: 4
 }

];
```

I would like to know how to do this with a `for/of` loop

Here is [the code I've attempted](https://repl.it/repls/TrainedGrowingTask?folderId=):

```
let obj = [];
for (i of arr){
  for (j of data){
    let innerObj={};
    innerObj.num = i
    obj.push(innerObj)
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = [{"no":3,"name":"drink"},{"no":90,"name":"eat"},{"no":20,"name":"swim"}];
const arr = [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,20,20,20,20,80,80];
const lookup = {};

// Loop over the duplicate array and create an
// object that contains the totals
for (let el of arr) {

  // If the key doesn't exist set it to zero,
  // otherwise add 1 to it
  lookup[el] = (lookup[el] || 0) + 1;  
}

const out = [];
// Then loop over the data updating the objects
// with the totals found in the lookup object
for (let obj of data) {
  lookup[obj.no] && out.push({
    no: obj.no,
    total: lookup[obj.no]
  });
}

document.querySelector('#lookup').textContent = JSON.stringify(lookup, null, 2);
document.querySelector('#out').textContent = JSON.stringify(out, null, 2);
```

```html
<h3>Lookup output</h3>
<pre id="lookup"></pre>

<h3>Main output</h3>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: what is 2 means? in that JSON.stringify @andy

Comment: ["indent 2 spaces"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: you didn console log ` lookup`, but the output is the result i need, how can it happened ??

Comment: It's not the same. Your required output is an array of objects. The lookup is just an object. But I'm glad it helped.

Comment: i still have no idea :(,

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: can i console.log Json.stringify? i have no idea about the variable `lookup`

Comment: I've updated the answer snippet to show the lookup and main output. That might help. And yes, you can `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))`.

Comment: well, the output is not same like i wish, if the no. not on arrays, we should not put it on array of object, and the ovject key should be `num: .....` and `total:...`

Comment: Final update done to match your expected output exactly.

Comment: well, if i have delete numbers in array and just show one numbers, your output undefined :D

Comment: `[ { no: 3, total: 9 },
  { no: 90, total: undefined },
  { no: 20, total: undefined } ]`

Comment: if the array only just say`  `[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]`

Comment: All you need to do is check that the number is a key in the lookup table. Answer amended.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this? You can map the existing data array and attach filtered array counts to each array object.

```
let data = [
  {
    no: 3,
    name: 'drink'
  },
  {
    no:90,
    name: 'eat'
  },
  {
    no:20,
    name: 'swim'
  }
]

const test = [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,90,20,20,20,20]

const result = data.map((item) => {
  return {
    num: item.no,
    total: test.filter(i => i === item.no).length // filters number array and then checks length
  }
})
```

Comment: how about if we use `for of` ??

Comment: If you haven't done the work yourself, and are asking for help, it's pretty bold to then be opinionated about the code you're then given.

Comment: You could do this but I don't see why you'd prefer this `const arr = [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,90,20,20,20,20];

let result = [];

for (let item of data) {
  const obj  = {
    num: item.no,
    total: arr.filter(i => i === item.no).length
  }
  result.push(obj);
}`

Comment: how about if the test array jus show 2 numbers from that object, we should not add the numbers which not show in the arrays

Comment: Just check for the filtered array length before pushing the object to the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can check next approach using a single `for/of` loop. But first I have to create a **Set** with valid ids, so I can discard `noise` data from the `test` array:

```js
const data = [
    {no: 3, name: 'drink'},
    {no: 90, name: 'eat'},
    {no: 20, name: 'swim'}
];

const userArr = [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,7,7,9,9,3,3,3,90,20,20,20,20];

let ids = new Set(data.map(x => x.no));
let newArr = [];

for (i of userArr)
{
   let found = newArr.findIndex(x => x.num === i)

   if (found >= 0)
       newArr[found].total += 1;
   else
       ids.has(i) && newArr.push({num: i, total: 1});
}

console.log(newArr);
```